# How do I set myself as "currently unemployed" in Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

The option seems to be unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to an explicit "I'm currently unemployed" would be to set the start and end dates of your previous job (or education curriculum) on your [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current/).

Additionally, you probably want to check out your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current), where you can set your job search status:

- Actively looking for a job
- Open, but not actively looking
- Not looking